# Adobe LiveCycle. Conditional character limit based on option selected from radio button

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a radio button that the user has to choose either A or B. Depending on the choice I would like it to affect the character limits for the rest of the form.

Sample code from the internet that controls the character limit from the form (Source: [Assure Dynamics](http://assuredynamics.com/index.php/portfolio/limiting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-field/)).

```
if (this.rawValue.length > 25)
{
var vInput = TextField3.rawValue.toString();
this.rawValue = vInput.substring(0,25);
}
```

I would like to modify the script such that the value 25 is changed to 50 if B is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a variable "limit" that is updated on the radio button onchange event?

```
var limit = 25;

function onRadioChange () {
    if(getElementById('radio50').checked) {
        limit = 50;
    } else {
        limit = 25;
    }
}

if (this.rawValue.length > limit) {
    var vInput = TextField3.rawValue.toString();
    this.rawValue = vInput.substring(0,limit);
}
```